# ASP.NET Identity 2 to 3

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-identity-3

Right, so..I think I'm confused!!

I have a few ASP.NET MVC 5 sites running using ASP.NET Identity 2.1 and everything is great. I am creating a new MVC 6 site and I would like the users to use there existing credentials that they use for other systems. I have already tried the below:

1. Migrating the ASP.NET identity 2 database to 3 (says it cannot as the tables already exist, I thought it would migrate the users in all honesty)
2. Tried getting MVC 6 to work with ASP.NET Identity 2.1 and failed miserably

I am just wondering what my options are since the documentation is not great on the new version, I get that there are DDL changes in the DB but I was kind of hoping there would be a way for my MVC 5 websites to carry on going as is with the .NET Identity 3 database being backwards compatible with 2.1.

My other option is to upgrade the MVC 5 apps to use Identity 3 which in turn I believe means updating them to MVC 6, which is something I don't really have the resources for, or to have a totally new Identity database (which seems the least fuss option).

Any opinions would be helpful, no doubt I have missed out some detail so happy to fill in the blanks should anyone have any further questions about the setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was doing the same thing, its a good deal of effort - and you will have to run db migrations, but first

The *new* **ASP Identity V3 Tables** &  Migration

[image: The ASP Identity V3 Tables & Migration]

The *new* **ASP Identity V3 Fields**

[image: The fields inside the users table, you can extend this, see below]

Configuring the tables
In Startup.cs and change services.AddIdentity

```
   services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, int>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

In ApplicationContext.cs and change the class to the following signature.

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>, int>
```

In ApplicationUser.cs and change the class to the following signature.

```
`public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int> {...}`
```

- Given all the changes I found it easier to delete everything in the
  migrations folder (except the migrations).  Go to command prompt on
  the directory of the project and type/add a migration like so `dotnet
  ef migrations add MyDatabaseHere -o Data\Migrations`. (-o Option is to specify target folder and not root folder)
- for any issues with migration I would simply drop the database and just deploy again.
- or you can automate with [this](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Database-Change-Deployment-Automation) I have not tried this

I got two migration scripts from EF, I was not sure why...  but for more references from github links [1](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/99) & [2](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/682)

Answer (score 2):

Implement IdentityServer3, it can hook directly into your existing ASP.Net Identity EF DB. Then use the other sites as oAuth clients, being MVC 5 and/or MVC 6 it wont matter because all they will be doing is passing secure tokens back and forth between your IdentityServer3 site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use identity 2 in Asp.Net Core and mantain the passwordhash in the database.Just add this code in startup.cs

```
 services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options => {
          options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2;
      });
```